# How to use a single WhatsApp Business number on two different phones?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm trying to use two different phones for one WhatsApp Business number due to them only allowing the use of one phone.

How to use a single WhatsApp Business number on two different phones? Can I do it by making an app think I'm using a tablet?

Comment: Why not install a Work profile and install Whatsapp Business in it too?

Comment: @Firelord, what is a work profile?

Comment: This might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919) because *WhatsApp doesn't support Android tablet*. Also, I think the wording "*use two phones*" is a bit unclear. Did you mean 1) you want to use the same WhatsApp account (phone number) on different devices? (AFAIK, not possible), or 2) you want to use different WhatsApp accounts (phone numbers) on the same device? (use parallel space)

Comment: @AndrewT. I clarified